# Syntax of If-Else in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, if-statement, syntax

I've been looking at other similar questions but I still can't work out the problem here. I'll preface this by saying that yes, this is homework, but I'm at the point where I don't know where I'm wrong. The task is to rewrite a recursive algorithm we were given, that returns 1 if n is 0, n if n is less than 5, else it does the last line of code here:

```
alg n = if (n == 0)
    then 1 
    else if (n<5) 
        then n
        else alg(n-1) * alg(n-2) * alg(n-3) * alg(n-4)
```

The error I get is a parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) in WinGHCi. I've checked lots of articles on how to properly structure if statements in Haskell but I'm still a beginner, so I have no idea where I'm going wrong. If somebody is able to tell me what in there is incorrect to avoid future mistakes, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Writing your code in a text editor and importing it into GHCI raised no syntax errors for me. Are you typing this interactively into GHCI?

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ to write the code and WinGHCi to execute it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the lines you wrote in isolation, as you can check by copying them into a new Haskell source file. If GHC is reporting an error on one of these lines, then the real error is probably just before these lines, perhaps an unmatched parenthesis or if-then with no else or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (and arguably more concise) approach could be considered, using *guards*:

```
alg n
    | n == 0 = 1 
    | n < 5 = n 
    | otherwise = alg(n-1) * alg(n-2) * alg(n-3) * alg(n-4)
```

Comment: While this answer isn't wrong, it doesn't address the question of why the original program doesn't compile, and it could give the impression that one must use guards rather than if/then/else here.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll clarify that this is an alternative.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is right there in the error message: your indentation is wrong. Specifically, you wrote

```
else if ...
  then ...
  else ...
```

The `then` and `else` keywords needs to be indented further than the matching `if` keyword:

```
else if ...
       then ...
       else ...
```

**Edit:** Nope, it turns it I'm wrong. I've tried with several different mis-indentations of `if`, and it all works fine. I have no idea what your original problem was. (Tab characters, maybe?)

Regardless, as @vikingsteve rightly points out, in this instance you can do it nicer with pattern guards:

```
alg n
    | condition1 = ...
    | condition2 = ...
    | condition3 = ...
    | condition4 = ...
```

It's usually much more readable to do it this way when possible. (It's not always so easy, of course...)

Comment: *Further* or at the same column.

Comment: This is not true, indentation plays no role in an `if` expression.

Comment: Thank you very much, folks! You've shown me how to use pattern guards and how to indent properly in Haskell.

Comment: @ReidBarton What makes you think indentation doesn't affect if-expressions?

Comment: Layout blocks occur only after the keywords `do`, `let`, `of` and `where` and their effect is to insert braces and semicolons. The syntax of an if-expression is just "`if` expr `then` expr `else` expr" which doesn't involve any semicolons. See https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.7 for more information about layout.

Comment: Unbelievable... It turns out it _does_ work if you indent it wrong. In spite of this: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/DoAndIfThenElse How utterly bizarre...

Comment: The issue behind DoAndIfThenElse is not that `if` requires indentation (it does not) but that `do` requires it.

Comment: @chi, can you expand on that?

Comment: @dfeuer Layout is a rule for introducing the `{`,`;`,`}` symbols in the source code. Some constructs use those symbols to split blocks into elements, e.g. `let` blocks, `do` blocks, etc. The `if` does not have any block to split, and the layout rule is immaterial for `if`. However, sometimes in a `do` block people like to start a line with `if ...` and then follow it with `then ...` and `else ...` at the same indentation level. This inserts an extra `;` since we are in a `do` block, and the parser complains (hence the proposal to loosen the parser). But a standalone `if` has no such issues.